# How to use Spring Boot build plugin with JavaFX app

Tags: maven, spring-boot, javafx, build, compiler-errors

I used Netbeans to generate a template for my JavaFX app.  It generated a POM.xml and the build section seems excessively complicated.  Furthermore, it unpacks ALL the dependencies every time i compile the project and it takes like 3 minutes every time.  Here is the relevant section of the POM.xml file :

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<organization>
    <name>MDenis</name>
</organization>

<dependencies>

    <!--SPRING-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!--HIBERNATE-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--HSQLDB-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!--LOMBOK-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!--LOG4J2-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludeScope>system</excludeScope>
                        <excludeGroupIds>junit,org.mockito,org.hamcrest</excludeGroupIds>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unpack-dependencies</id>

                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>${java.home}/../bin/javapackager</executable>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>-createjar</argument>
                            <argument>-nocss2bin</argument>
                            <argument>-appclass</argument>
                            <argument>${mainClass}</argument>
                            <argument>-srcdir</argument>
                            <argument>${project.build.directory}/classes</argument>
                            <argument>-outdir</argument>
                            <argument>${project.build.directory}</argument>
                            <argument>-outfile</argument>
                            <argument>${project.build.finalName}.jar</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-cli</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>                            
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>${java.home}/bin/java</executable>
                        <commandlineArgs>${runfx.args}</commandlineArgs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>  
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <bootclasspath>${sun.boot.class.path}${path.separator}${java.home}/lib/jfxrt.jar</bootclasspath>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.16</version>
            <configuration>
                <additionalClasspathElements>
                    <additionalClasspathElement>${java.home}/lib/jfxrt.jar</additionalClasspathElement>
                </additionalClasspathElements>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This is my first JavaFX project, in my other projects i just use this build section and everything works fine :

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

However, when trying to use it with this project, i get the following error :

```
The parameters 'executable' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec are missing or invalid
```

Why won't this work with a JavaFX project?  It seems like it wants to execute goals that are not even in my POM file.

***EDIT***

I do see that goal in the effective POM tab but I don't know enough about Maven to make sense of it, I can't change anything in the effective section anyway.  Anyone knows how to make the Spring Boot plugin work with a JavaFX desktop app?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally managed to make this work without unpacking the dependencies every time i compile.  I used the `de.felixroske.jfxsupport.AbstractJavaFxApplicationSupport` class to extend my main class from, put `launch(args);` in the main method, and I now have the following code in the build section of the POM.XML file :

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
            </executions>  
            <configuration>
                <executable>${java.home}/bin/java</executable>
                <commandlineArgs>${runfx.args}</commandlineArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: You are more than welcome, thank you for your help.  Turns out you don't need the jfxsupport library, the launch() method is present in the standard JavaFX Application class as well and it works fine too!

Answer (score 3):

You need to refactor the pom file. The configuration must go outside of the executions, like this:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>exec</goal>
      </goals>
          <configuration>
            <executable>${java.home}/../bin/javapackager</executable>
              <arguments>
                <argument>-createjar</argument>
                <argument>-nocss2bin</argument>
                <argument>-appclass</argument>
                <argument>${mainClass}</argument>
                <argument>-srcdir</argument>
                <argument>${project.build.directory}/classes</argument>
                <argument>-outdir</argument>
                <argument>${project.build.directory}</argument>
                <argument>-outfile</argument>
                <argument>${project.build.finalName}.jar</argument>
              </arguments>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        <execution>
          <id>default-cli</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>exec</goal>                            
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>  
    <configuration>
      <executable>${java.home}/bin/java</executable>
      <commandlineArgs>${runfx.args}</commandlineArgs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: how does that help me use the spring boot plugin INSTEAD of all this stuff?

Comment: I missread, sorry. What you have to do there is add an id to the execution tag likevthis:

Comment: i don't want to unpack the dependencies, i want to use the spring boot plugin as i specified in my original post.  The short build section i posted that uses the spring boot plugin works in all my other projects except this one and the only difference is the use of JavaFX.

Comment: sorry this was an example how to add an id to your execution, you can call it whatever you want: <execution> <id>foooo</id>

Comment: i mean the obvious is removing the executions all for one to have the unpacking stopped if that is what you're asking. The tip above will make the spring-boot-maven-plugin work

Comment: So i need to put the spring boot plugin as well as the exec-maven-plugin and remove the unpack dependencies section?

Comment: I tried this and the resulting jar file is tiny.  The project builds properly but I get this error when running it in Netbeans : Unknown command :-jar.